# Regex .htaccess with UTF-8

Tags: .htaccess

i've got .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category?$ category.php
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) category.php?name=$1
```

Need to even use letters "ě,š,č,ř,ž,ý,á,í,é" etc..

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category?$ category.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)$ category.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

Which accepts all characters